# Beautifulsoup error while deploying to heroku

Tags: django, heroku, beautifulsoup

i am trying to deploy my Django app to heroku. When i push heroku master it gives an error in the shell.

It says push rejected because no matching distribution found for beautifulsoup4=4.0.0b3 it says could not find a version that satisfies the requirement beautifulsoup4=4.0.0b3

How can i solve this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the requirements.txt file? Search for that line and take away "b3" in `beautifulsoup4=4.0.0b3` then again `git add requirements.txt` -> `git -commit "init..."` and finally `git push heroku master`